# Не работают ссылки из-за js

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
В чём проблема?
https://codepen.io/free3p/pen/gWrZYV?editors=1010

```
(function() {

  // Definition of caller element
  var getTriggerElement = function(el) {
    var isCollapse = el.getAttribute('data-collapse');
    if (isCollapse !== null) {
      return el;
    } else {
      var isParentCollapse = el.parentNode.getAttribute('data-collapse');
      return (isParentCollapse !== null) ? el.parentNode : undefined;
    }
  };

  // A handler for click on toggle button
  var collapseClickHandler = function(event) {
    var triggerEl = getTriggerElement(event.target);
    // If trigger element does not exist
    if (triggerEl === undefined) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

    // If the target element exists
    var targetEl = document.querySelector(triggerEl.getAttribute('data-target'));
    if (targetEl) {
      triggerEl.classList.toggle('-active');
      targetEl.classList.toggle('-on');
    }
  };

  // Delegated event
  document.addEventListener('click', collapseClickHandler, false);

})(document, window);
```

Comment: в ветку с event.preventDefault(); попадает. event.preventDefault() - останавливает переход.

Comment: @tcpack4 спасибо

Comment: @tcpack4 оформите комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: Если вам помогли то нажмите на галочку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попадая в ветку

```
if (triggerEl === undefined) {
```

код

```
event.preventDefault()
```

блокирует переход по ссылке.